# Can't send email from a bash script

Tags: email, gmail, bash-scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
SMTPTO=akshaysingh@gmail.com
SMTPFROM=akshaysingh1@gmail.com
SMTPSERVER=smtp.googlemail.com:587
SMTPUSER=akshaysingh
SMTPPASS=password
MESSAGE="123"
SUBJECT="THIS IS END."
sendemail -f $SMTPFROM -t $SMTPTO -u $SUBJECT -m $MESSAGE -s $SMTPSERVER -xu $SMTPUSER -xp $SMTPPASS -o tls=yes
```

It's giving the error:

```
sendemail[3854]: ERROR => Connection attempt to smtp.googlemail.com:587 failed: IO::Socket::INET6: connect: Connection refused
```

Comment: i also install sendEmail pckage

Comment: "If you tried configuring your SMTP server on port 465 (with SSL) and port 587 (with TLS), but are still having trouble sending mail, try configuring your SMTP to use port 25 (with SSL). "

Comment: [Problems sending mail with POP or IMAP](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en)

Comment: Doesn't smtp.googlemail.com need a complete e-mail address as username? So SMTPUSER=akshaysingh@gmail.com or something? And did you set the "Allow less secure apps access" to ON in https://myaccount.google.com/security (all the way at the bottom of that page) or at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps directly? (Don't forget to set it back if it doesn't help)

Answer (score 1):

You have your SMTP server set to:

```
SMTPSERVER=smtp.googlemail.com:587
```

But according to [the official Google documentation on SMTP setup](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en), the FQDN of SMTP Service should be `smtp.gmail.com`. So perhaps change that to:

```
SMTPSERVER=smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Additionally, your SMTP user is this:

```
SMTPUSER=akshaysingh
```

But Google documentation clearly states it should be the full `[username]@gmail.com` address:

> Your full Gmail or Google Apps email address required for
>   authentication

So perhaps change that to:

```
SMTPUSER=akshaysingh@gmail.com
```

Comment: i also tried but it tells same error and also re update send email package